# update table removing some data

Tags: sql, command

Could anyone help me with a command on SQL to update a column as this example bellow.

```
IP : 192.168.010.001
```

I need to remove zero and update column to be like this:

```
IP : 192.168.10.1
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove the last four characters, then most databases support `LEFT()`:

```
update table t
    set col = left(col, length(col) - 4);
```

The name of the `length()` function also differs among databases (typically either `len()` or `length()`).  And `substr()`/`substring()` could be used instead of `left()`.

EDIT:

Ahhh, Jeffrey pointed out that the above is an incorrect interpretation.  I misread the numbers.  There is a method to do this, which is pretty database independent.  Generally, there will not be more than two zeros after a period (if there are three, then you probably want the third).  So:

```
update table t
     set ip = replace(replace(ip, '.0', '.'), '.0', '.')
     where ip like '%.0%';
```

Comment: It looks like his intention is to remove leading zeros in any of the number sets. In the example it would need to remove them from the 3rd and 4th set.

Answer (score 0):

which Database you are using , if you are using Sybase you can try str_replace and use to replace pattern like '.0' or '.00' to '' . 
Query could be something like this

```
`update X set Y=str_replace(Y,'.0','.') where Y like '%.0%' `
```

and

```
`update X set Y=str_replace(Y,'.00','.') where Y like '%.00%' `
```

Comment: Thanks for your repply. I tried this :  select address from TCP
`update address set Y=str_replace(Y,'.0','.') where Y like '%.0%'  but it show a error : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'str_replace' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @PauloSilva what database you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple replace twice will also work:

```
replace(replace('192.168.010.001','.0','.'),'.0','.')
```

or

```
IP_Field =  replace(replace(IP_Field,'.0','.'),'.0','.')
```

Comment: I tried this: select address from TCP
  update address set address = replace('192.168.010.001','.0','.'),'.0','.') but it show a error : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '.0'.

Comment: You need two replaces, one for each extra zero.